# Passing multiple class objects to razor view through controller in mvc, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I am trying to perform CRUD operations on two classes `PurchaseDetail` and `ItemDetail`. Made `PurchaseDetail` a base class and `ItemDetail` as child class. So on a single razor view I am passing the child class object. Now when I'm performing CRUD operation on child class everything works fine. But when trying the same with base class I'm getting null object while adding data by calling a create(ItemDetail obj), on HttpPost.

Any solution for this? Is it a good practice to pass multiple classes to a view by using inheritance?

Edit
Elaboration:

```
public class PurchaseDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "PPRF Name")]
    public string pprfName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Department")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentSerial { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> MaterialTypes { get; set; }
```

Above class is my base class with few properties. Then Below is my child class.

```
public class ItemDetail: PurchaseDetail
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int ItemCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ItemCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
```

If I would take both in different pages there was not any problem. But I want to pass both class onto same view so I went for Inheritance. I am popping up form for ItemDetail from the same view, to add an item.

```
@model AIIMSINTRANET.Models.ItemDetail
```

Firstly I am inserting ItemDetail by using Ajax call. Here things are working fine.

```
public JsonResult Add(ItemDetail item)
{ 
    //Insert Logic
}
```

After this I want to insert PurchaseDetail in it's respective table. Since the view was same so every fields like TextBox, Dropdowns were filled while calling this method.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ItemDetail obj = new ItemDetail(); 

        obj.DeptIndentNo = GetIndentNumber2();
        obj.IndentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        obj.MaterialTypes = PurchaseProposalDO.PopulateMaterialType();
        //Initialized all other fields 
     }
```

Even fields like DropDown of ItemDetail class got populated during above function call. Now when I am submitting the form to Insert PurchaseDetail, it calls below function:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ItemDetail obj)
    {
        // Insert Logic Here
    }
```

Now here is my problem. Why am I getting obj as null ?
Even when I am inputting everything.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.pprfName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.pprfName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pprfName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Sample code would be helpful to be able to understand your hierarchy and to identify where you are getting a null object. I'm guessing the problem is model binding though and the solution would be to using custom model binding. Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the class definitions in question it's hard to answer definitively, but it sounds like what you've got is an Order Header/Order Line type relationship. If that's the case, using inheritance is absolutely the wrong approach for solving this. You should use a view model that encapsulates the other two objects and pass that. Something like:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public PurchaseDetail PurchaseDetail { get; set; }
    public ItemDetail ItemDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Or, if there could be many `ItemDetail`s for a single `PurchaseDetail`:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public PurchaseDetail PurchaseDetail { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemDetail> ItemDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could have the view model pass only the properties of interest to the view. Again, without seeing the definition of the classes it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you Craig for your prompt reply. I have added my codes, please have a look.

Comment: From what I can see you should not be using inheritance but rather a view-model. It does not seem like an ItemDetail "is-a" PurchaseDetail (which is the litmus test for inheritance). Change your model and see if you still have a problem.